# is there a way find substring index through a regular expression in python?

Tags: python, regex, indexing, string-matching

i want to find a substring 's index postion,but the substring is long and hard to expression(multiline,& even you need escape for it ) so i want to use regex to match them,and return the substring's index,
the function like str.find or str.rfind ,
is there some package help for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this might work:

```
import re

def index(longstr, pat):
    rx = re.compile(r'(?P<pre>.*?)({0})'.format(pat))
    match = rx.match(longstr)
    return match and len(match.groupdict()['pre'])
```

Then:

```
>>> index('bar', 'foo') is None
True
>>> index('barfoo', 'foo')
3
>>> index('\xbarfoo', 'foo')
2
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the `.start()` method on the result object of a successful match (the so called *match object*):

```
 mo = re.search('foo', veryLongString)
 if mo:
      return mo.start()
```

If the match was successful, `mo.start()` will give you the (first) index of the matching substring within the searched string.

Answer (score 0):

regular expression "re" package should be of help

- http://docs.python.org/library/re.html
- http://diveintopython3.ep.io/regular-expressions.html
- http://www.doughellmann.com/PyMOTW/re/